# Changing background in AS3 and accelerometer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, accelerometer

I'm making a mobile application It's main features involve a digital timer clock starting once my the accelerometer reaches a certain point

My code is as follows :

```
``var varAccelerometer:Accelerometer;
varAccelerometer = new Accelerometer();

//Accelerometer Eventlistener Listens for data from the Accelerometer
varAccelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, funMoveObject);
//Data from the accelerometer is passed to the Parameter eventData
function funMoveObject(eventData:AccelerometerEvent):void

{
////////////////Start Timer Controls///////////////////
trace(eventData.accelerationY);
if (eventData.accelerationY < -0.15){
trace("starting");
myTimer.start();        
}`
```

This is my accelerometer data, once it reaches -0.15 my digital timer activates. I need my background image to change to another background image once accelerometer reaches -0.15 Can you advise me on where I would need to place my second image on my timeline and what AS3 code I will need

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this is a relatively simple matter, however, it depends largely on the structure of your timeline. There are hundreds of possible ways to make a timeline, so it is hard to give a rather solid answer.

That said, the method I most recommend is to create a MovieClip object called "backgroundImage" in your project's library. Put it on your timeline, on a new layer. That layer should be placed below all the other layers on the timeline, to ensure the backgroundImage object is behind everything else on your screen. (NOTE: Be sure to give that object on your screen an instance name! Click the object on your stage, and click Properties, and type "backgroundImage" in the instance name.)

In that MovieClip, you will create two frames - one has your default background image, and the other has the second background image you want. On the Actions tab for each frame, put the code:

```
stop();
```

That ensures that the timeline does not "play," but remains on whatever frame you set it to.

Now, you can use this line of code to change to the new background:

```
backgroundImage.gotoAndStop(2);
```

And this line of code to change to the original background:

```
backgroundImage.gotoAndStop(1);
```

Everything I just described involves basic Flash skills. If you need extra help with these, there are hundreds of good tutorials on using Flash CS5. I would go watch those, and then come back to my answer.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm familiar with gotoandStop but am having troubles implimenting it into my design. I can always wait until class next week to show my teacher. I'm running into errors once I publish my file with my background staying constant (it flickers) and it changing to frame2 upon accelerometer -0.15

Comment: The flickering indicates that the backgroundImage object timeline has not stopped. Is the "stop();" code on each frame INSIDE that object? If so, try gotoAndPlay() instead of gotoAndStop(), and see if that fixes it.